# Is there any way I can 'stream' a PDO query result 'into' the output buffer, instead of storing it into a string?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There's little to be added, if you see the title of this question.

I've got a query that retrieves a single row from a MySQL table, and I'm interested in a particular column, which is a BLOB. I would like PHP to write it into the output buffer, instead of storing ~500 KB into a string (*which furthermore I'm not sure would be binary-safe*).

PDOStatement functions like:

```
string PDOStatement::fetchColumn ([ int $column_number = 0 ] )
```

don't help me.

Can you help giving me at least a direction? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I know storing ~500 KB stuff inside a DB table is not good, but it's not my choice, I just have to stick with it.

Comment: `I know storing ~500 KB stuff inside a DB table is not good` using big blobs does not need to be bad. It really depends on your circumstances.

Comment: Strings are binary-safe in PHP, at least until they decided to incorporate built-in UTF encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php). This loads the data into a stream, which can then be used with f* functions, including outputting directly to the browser with fpassthru. This is the example code from that page:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select contenttype, imagedata from images where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
?>
```

The key here is that after `$stmt->execute()`, you call `$stmt->bindColumn('columnName', $stream, PDO::PARAM_LOB);`, then call `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)` to get the row (where the values are stored into the bound PHP variables). This is how I used it in Drupal, tested and working; it includes a lot of extra cache handling that should speed up your clients and only requires you to keep track of the Last-Modified time of your blobs:

```
<?php
$rfc2822_format = 'D, d M Y H:i:s e';

// This is basically the Drupal 7 way to create and execute a prepared
// statement; the `->execute()` statement returns a PDO::Statement object.
// This is the equivalent SQL:
//   SELECT f.fileType,f.fileSize,f.fileData,f.lastModified
//   FROM mfiles AS f WHERE fileID=:fileID
// (with :fileID = $fileID)
$statement = db_select('mfiles', 'f')
  ->fields('f', array('fileType', 'fileSize', 'fileData', 'lastModified'))
  ->condition('fileID', $fileID, '=')
  ->execute();
// All of the fields need to be bound to PHP variables with this style.
$statement->bindColumn('fileType', $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$statement->bindColumn('fileSize', $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindColumn('fileData', $fileData, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$statement->bindColumn('lastModified', $lastModified, PDO::PARAM_STR, 19);

$success = false;

// If the row was fetched successfully...
if ($statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
  // Allow [public] caching, but force all requests to ask the server if
  // it's been modified before serving a cache [no-cache].
  header('Cache-Control: public no-cache');

  // Format the Last-Modified time according to RFC 2822 and send the
  // Last-Modified HTTP header to aid in caching.
  $lastModified_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',
    $lastModified, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  $lastModified_formatted = $lastModified_datetime->format($rfc2822_format);
  header('Last-Modified: ' . $lastModified_formatted);

  // If the client requested If-Modified-Since, and the specified date/time
  // is *after* $datetime (the Last-Modified date/time of the API call), give
  // a HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified response and exit (do not output the rest of
  // the page).
  if (array_key_exists('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE', $_SERVER)) {
    // Ignore anything after a semicolon (old browsers sometimes added stuff
    // to this request after a semicolon).
    $p = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 2);
    // Parse the RFC 2822-formatted date.
    $since = DateTime::createFromFormat($rfc2822_format, $p[0]);

    if ($lastModified_datetime <= $since) {
      header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
      exit;
    }
  }

  // Create an ETag from the hash of it and the Last-Modified time, and send 
  // it in an HTTP header to aid in caching.
  $etag = md5($lastModified_formatted . 'mfile:' . $fileID);
  header('ETag: "' . $etag . '"');

  // If the client requested If-None-Match, and the specified ETag is the
  // same as the hashed ETag, give a HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified response and
  // exit (do not output the rest of the page).
  if (array_key_exists('HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH', $_SERVER) && $etag ==
      str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']))) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    exit;
  }

  // Set the content type so that Apache or whatever doesn't send it as
  // text/html.
  header('Content-Type: ' . $fileType);

  // Set the content length so that download dialogs can estimate how long it
  // will take to load the file.
  header('Content-Length: ' . $fileSize);

  // According to some comments on the linked page, PDO::PARAM_LOB might
  // create a string instead of a stream.
  if (is_string($fileData)) {
    echo $fileData;
    $success = true;
  } else {
    $success = (fpassthru($fileData) !== false);
  }
}
?>
```

Aside: If you need to provide a filename, a quick and dirty solution is to add the filename to the actual URL referencing the file; for `http://example.com/fileurl.php`, use `http://example.com/fileurl.php/filename.jpg`. This may not work if something is already interpreting the path info (like Drupal); the "better" solution is to send the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.jpg`, but this also prevents clients from viewing the image directly in the browser (although this may be a good thing depending on your situation).

Comment: Streaming in PDO is since 2007 up until now 2015 not available. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913

Answer (score 3):

I strongly believe the batch processing with Doctrine or any kind of iterations with MySQL (PDO or mysqli) are just an illusion.

@dimitri-k provided a nice explanation especially about unit of work. The problem is the miss leading: "**$query->iterate()**" which doesn't really iterate over the data source. It's **just an \Traversable wrapper** around already **fully fetched** data source.

An example demonstrating that even removing Doctrine abstraction layer completely from the picture, we will still run into **memory issues**:

```
echo 'Starting with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";

$pdo  = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=HOST", "USER", "PW");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_big_table LIMIT 100000');
$stmt->execute();

while ($rawCampaign = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // echo $rawCampaign['id'] . "\n";
}

echo 'Ending with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";
```

**Output:**

```
Starting with memory usage: 6 MB 
Ending with memory usage: 109.46875 MB
```

Here, the disappointing **getIterator()** method:

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $data = $this->fetchAll();

    return new \ArrayIterator($data);
}
```

You can use my little library to **actually** stream heavy tables using PHP Doctrine or DQL or just pure SQL. However you find appropriate: https://github.com/EnchanterIO/remote-collection-stream

Comment: JFYI, [buffered queries](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd). So the solution is much simpler actually

Comment: Ah that's interesting. Thx @YourCommonSense.